# How to trigger the toggle on one click instead of two

Tags: javascript

I am using a simple toggle like this:

```
   function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

and my HTML is like this:

```
 <div id="income">
 <h5 onclick="toggle_visibility('incometoggle');">INCOME</h5>
 <div id="incometoggle">
    <h6>Income Total</h6> 
 </div>    </div>
```

At the moment, I need to click twice on the heading to get the div to close. How can I make it close with just one click?

http://jsfiddle.net/4w3ynj40/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first check the condition display none

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e.style.display == 'none') e.style.display = 'block';
    else e.style.display = 'none';
}
```

jquery

```
  $("h5").click(function() {
    $("#incometoggle").toggle(); 
  });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/txa2x9qq/1/)

Comment: At least you can mention what you have changed ('none' to 'block' and vice versa). And it's not a bad idea also to mention why OP's code doesn't work.

Comment: Actually the problem with the original code is in fact, that `e.style.display` is empty at the begining (there is standard `display: block` for `div` in browser, yes, but `e.style` works with the styles of particular element, which are empty at the begining).

Comment: yes you are right but i didn't know how to tell in english

Answer (score 0):

```
var hFive = document.getElementsByTagName('h5')[0];
hFive.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var e = document.getElementById('incometoggle');
    if (e.style.display == 'block') {
        e.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        e.style.display = 'block';
    }
}, false);
```

Modify the part of inline javascript and I use `addEventListener`.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4w3ynj40/2/)